# switchbuf=useopen for quickfix entries, but not for location list entries

Tags: vim

I like to use `switchbuf=useopen`, so that when I select an entry from the quickfix list (which, for me, is usually an error from a test run), if I have the file open in a window already (which I usually do—it's usually in the test or the implementation), it reuses that window.

However, I also sometimes use the location list, usually for grepping a codebase. The whole point of the location list is that it's window-specific: each window has its own. But if I have `switchbuf=useopen` and the next location list entry is for a file with an open window, `:lnext` will move me into that window, just as with the quickfix list. Then, a subsequent `:lnext` won't do anything, because *this* window doesn't have a location list.

Is there a way to make the location list not respect `'switchbuf'`? I can't imagine why you'd ever want the behavior Vim is exhibiting.

Comment: Seems like a bug. `:h switchbuf` doesn't mention the location list it only refers to quickfix commands. You should ask on one of the vim mailing lists.

Comment: The location list is local to a window unlike the quickfix list

Comment: @PeterRincker: Right. That's why I don't find its behavior with `'switchbuf'` very useful.

Comment: I miss read the issue. I think @FDinoff has the right idea